# Application-specific keymapping

Tags: linux, xorg, gentoo, keymap

In general, I want to make specific keymaps for application, that working only in it and doesn't affect other apps.

For example, I already use my Caps key to toggle input language (via xorg.conf), but I want Capslock to behave like Esc in vim.
Looks like `xmodmap` doesn't have any options related to that.

Comment: X doesn't have any such facility, but your window manager or desktop environment may have one. What is it?

Comment: Gnome, maybe there is some third-party applications too?

Comment: Unless it is server related it has no valid reason to be moved, and will most likely be sent back here. However you can try the new [Unix SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) site. They are still in beta and has a much smaller Linux community but the core focus is Linux. There is no migration path to the Linux site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution in [evrouter](http://www.bedroomlan.org/projects/evrouter). It maps any keyboard event onto keypress in X.Org if active window title is matched by regexp you specify. It also helps me to deal with Zoom key on my Microsoft Natural Keyboard.
The bad thing is default X keypress also occurs.